# IOS Swift Post Request return something not clear

Tags: ios, swift, post, httprequest

I know this is probably one of the most up questions in stackoverflow, but i can't seems to understand why this is happning, maybe i am not looking at something.. maybe i am just new to ios.. so this is what is going..

i got a simple post funciton who looks like that :

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://10.0.0.153/api/User/Login")!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let params = [
                "UserName": "alon",
                "Password": "1234"
        ]
        request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in

          // print(request.HTTPBody)
          //  print(params)
           // print(error)
           // print(response!)
            print(data!)
        })

        task.resume()
```

and i got a .net api who looks like that :

```
 public string LoginToSystem(Users User)
        {
            try
            {
               if (User.UserName == "alon" && User.Password == "1234")
                {
                    return "You have login successfully";
                }
                return "User or password is bad";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

when i post to the server the params is working great, i got the information and everything is working! but. when i get the information back, this is what i get in data :

```
<22596f75 20686176 65206c6f 67696e20 73756363 65737366 756c6c79 22>
```

is there any information why? i am returning a string, you can see it in the asp.net function.

thanks! good day and thanks again.

Comment: Did you check the data type (class) of `data` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `data` is an `NSData`. Try convert it to String. Using

```
let str = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(str)
```

Comment: Thanks. working, you are a quick man. thanks! i will accept this answer in 9 minutes.. it seems that you cant too quick.